# How do I bitmask these tiles?

Tags: tilemap, godot, tile-bitmasking

Using Godot. I can't figure out how to bitmask these tiles in order to autotile them.
I've examined the templates shown in the [Godot Docs Tilemaps tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/using_tilemaps.html), but none seem appropriate. My own attempts to solve this through trial and error have left me confused and frustrated. The tiles are 32x32 pixels, and I'm fairly sure I need a 3x3 minimal masking layout.
[image: 38-tile tilemap]

My most recent attempt is almost workable:
[image]

Comment: There are a lot of tiles missing in the tileset. Where do you have it from?

Comment: The set is from here: https://elthen.itch.io/2d-pixel-art-forest-tileset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tileset is not ideal to use for autotiling, as many common pieces are missing, for example the L shape. I modified the tileset and used 160x160 wide tiles, this is the result:

[image: tilemap with tileset]

The blue checkerboard means that the cell is ignored, so it could be either filled or empty.